# A question on analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f(z)$ is analytic in $\overline{D}_1(0)$. Let $z_n$=$\frac{1}{n}$, and the $f(z_n)=\frac{z_n}{z_n+1}$ for every positive integer $n$. Clearly 0 is the accumulation point of $z_n$ . From this can we say that $f(z)=z/(z+1)$ in $\overline{D}_1(0)$?If so how can it be proved? Any assistance will be appreciated

Comment: $g(z) = {z \over 1+z}$ is analytic in $B(0,1)$ and $h(z) = f(z)-g(z)$ is analytic there too. Since $h(z_n) = 0$ and $z_n$ has an accumulation point inside $B(0,1)$ then $h=0$ on $B(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is an easy consequence of an improved version of the so called [Identity Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem).